# Adding release time to sine wave generation with AudioBufferList

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I've been trying to add release (or decay) time on a sine wave generation project, taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000552/ios-sine-wave-generation-audible-clicking) example as ground. What I basically want is not the sound to cut off so drastically and add some release at end when I stop generating it.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start some number of samples, say 5 to 50 milliseconds or your decided release time, before you want silence, and multiply your sine wave samples by a ramp that decreases from 1.0 to 0.0 over that time interval. Linear decrease is OK, but a raised cosine (0.5 + 0.5 * cos(pi*t)) might be better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense but should I create them before even start playing the real samples? The idea is to avoid a little glitch I'm having while stopping the wave.